# Counter variable is not working as it should in my do while loop

Tags: java

I'm not understanding why the counter variable for positives isn't holding the correct number? I enter four positives and three negatives, that should be the correct output. 0 is not to be counted towards positives. I've also tried prefix increment instead of postfix increment, that didn't help either. I'm new at a very beginner level.

Here's my input and output:

```
Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: 4
Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: 3
Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: 2
Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: 1
Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: -4
Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: -3
Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: -2
Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: 0
num of postives 3 and num of negatives 3 <----- output wrong
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /**
         * my pesducode
         * enter an integer, input ends if 0: 
         * while input != 0
         *     if input > 0
         *         postives = postiveCount++
         *     else
         *         negatives = negativeCount++
         *     total+= input
         *  end loop
         * totalNumsEnter = postive + negatives
         * avg = total/ totalNumsEnter
         */
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        int postiveCount = 0;
        int postives = 0;
        int negatives = 0;
        int negativeCount = 0;
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            
            if(num > 0){
               postives = postiveCount++;
            }
            else{
                negatives = negativeCount++;
            }
        }while( num != 0);
        System.out.printf("num of postives %d and num of negatives %d", postives,negatives);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: having both a `postives` (you misspelled positive) and a `postiveCount` is not necessary. the ++ operator increments the current variable. You can simply have postiveCount++ and print the postiveCount.

Comment: Trying your suggestion it did not work as it should of, when I entered five positives and three negatives. I received four negatives as my output and five positives. The only way I received the correct number of output of negatives and positives was changing the else to else if and check if negative is less than 0 as ewong suggested. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the else statement to the following would ignore the 0.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        int positiveCount = 0;
        int negativeCount = 0;
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            
            if(num > 0){
               positiveCount++;
            }
            else if (num < 0){
                negativeCount++;
            }
        }while( num != 0);
        System.out.printf("num of positives %d and num of negatives %d", positiveCount, negativeCount);
        input.close();
```

Another option (though it uses a nested if) is the following:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        int positiveCount = 0;
        int negativeCount = 0;
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter an integer, the input end if it is 0: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            
            if(num >= 0){
               if (num != 0) {
                 positiveCount++;
               }
            }
            else{
                negativeCount++;
            }
        }while( num != 0);
        System.out.printf("num of positives %d and num of negatives %d", positiveCount, negativeCount);
        input.close();
```

Comment: @grandmasterkuki  my apologies.  I've fixed the code such that 1) it's using the correct variables, 2) positives/positiveCount variable names have been fixed.

Comment: Would you say it's not always necessary to have a else when using a if and else if statement? @ewong

Comment: @grandmasterkuki somewhat depends on the conditions you require, I believe.  Since you require not counting 0, then you need to have two conditions to filter out 0.